# Mocking and Expecting from a Class instance created using new operator in Google Mock

Tags: googletest, googlemock

Need your inputs regarding the below:
I am facing an issue regarding how to write a mock for a base class (StackBT) of which an instance is created in the derived class's constructor (ApplicationBT) that I want to test.
My intention is to write a mock for the StackBT class (Mock_StackBT) and then link this to the unit test so that the instance of the mock is created when doing "new StackBT()" in ApplicationBT's constructor. So that using this I can mock the expectations on StackBT class while testing ApplicationBT class.

```
out/linux_host/obj/TestApplicationBT.o: In function `TestApplicationBT::SetUp()':
tst/_src/TestApplicationBT.cpp:33: undefined reference to `mockPtr_StackBT'
out/linux_host/lib/libServer.a(ApplicationBT.o): In function `ApplicationBT::init()':
/_src/ApplicationBT.cpp:36: undefined reference to `StackBT::registerCallbacks()'
/_src/ApplicationBT.cpp:43: undefined reference to `StackBT::sendBTMacAddress(std::string)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/linux_host/bin/Test] Error 1
```

I get the above compiler error while compiling the below code snippet:

```
StackBT.h:
class StackBT
{
   StackBT(){}

   void registerCallbacks();
   void sendBTMacAddress(std::string str);
}

Mock_StackBT.h:
#include "gtest/gtest.h" 
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include <string>
using ::testing::NiceMock;
class Mock_StackBT;
extern NiceMock < Mock_StackBT >* mockPtr_StackBT;
class Mock_StackBT: public StackBT
{
   Mock_StackBT(){}
   MOCK_METHOD0(registerCallbacks, void());
   MOCK_METHOD1(sendBTMacAddress, void(std::string str));
}

Mock_StackBT.cpp:
#include "Mock_StackBT.h" 
NiceMock < Mock_StackBT >* mockPtr_StackBT;
void registerCallbacks()
{
   mockPtr_StackBT->registerCallbacks();
}

void sendBTMacAddress(std::string str)
{
   mockPtr_StackBT->sendBTMacAddress(std::string str);
}

ApplicationBT.h:
class ApplicationBT
{
   public:
   ApplicationBT() : mpoStackBT(new StackBT())

   void init()
   {
      mpoStackBT->registerCallbacks();
      mpoStackBT->sendBTMacAddress("AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL");
   }

   friend class TestApplicationBT;

   scoped_ptr<StackBT> mpoStackBT;
}

TestApplicationBT.h
class TestApplicationBT : public ::testing::Test
{
   protected:
      virtual void SetUp ()
      {
     mockPtr_StackBT = &stackBTMock;
         ptrApplicationBT = new ApplicationBT();
      }
      void TearDown()
      {
         delete ptrApplicationBT;
      }
   public:
      TestApplicationBT ()
      {
      }

      ~TestApplicationBT ()
      {
         ptrApplicationBT = NULL;
      }

      scoped_ptr<ApplicationBT> ptrApplicationBT;
      StackBT* ptrStackBT;
      NiceMock<Mock_StackBT> stackBTMock;
};

TEST_F(TestApplicationBT, Init)
{
   EXPECT_CALL(stackBTMock, registerCallbacks() ).Times(1);
   EXPECT_CALL(stackBTMock, sendBTMacAddress(_) ).Times(1);
   ptrApplicationBT->init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are using `mockPtr_StackBT` in `TestApplicationBT.cpp`, but it is defined in
`Mock_StackBT.cpp`. The second issue is that the call to `ApplicationBT::init` method calls functions 
`registerCallbacks` and `sendBTMacAddress` through pointer `mpoStackBT`, but if you look closely at
the constructor for class `ApplicationBT` you will se that this pointer is set to an object of class `StackBT`
and not `Mock_StackBT`. This causes a linker error because you did not implement functions
`registerCallbacks` and `sendBTMacAddress` for class `StackBT`, you have only declared them.

The main problem is that you are not swapping your real implementation with a mock, your approach is
not correct. First of all, you are not suppossed to create implementations for functions `registerCallbacks`
and `sendBTMacAddress` in the mock class, googlemock does that for you (file Mock_StackBT.cpp is completely
unnecessary). Also, you need a common interface for classes `StackBT` and `Mock_StackBT` so you can 
switch implementations. Here is how you do it:

Create interface:

```
class IStackBT
{
public:
    virtual IStackBT()  {}
    virtual void registerCallbacks() = 0;
    virtual sendBTMacAddress(std::string str) = 0;
}
```

Create class for production:

```
class StackBT : public IStackBT
{
public:
    void registerCallbacks()  override
    {
        // Your code that registers callbacks
    }
    void sendBTMacAddress(std::string str) override
    {
        // Your code that sends mac address
    }
}
```

Create mock class:

```
class StackBTMock : public IStackBT
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(registerCallbacks, void());
    MOCK_METHOD1(sendBTMacAddress, void(std::string str));
}
```

Now, make your class `ApplicationBT` hold a `IStackBT` pointer and use some form of factory method
to create a real or mock object, depending on the fact if you are building unit test or deployment code. There 
are several ways, here is how I did it on my `gmock` project. Create a preprocessor define for your unit testing
project that indicates the code is built for unit tests. If it is, for example, named `MY_UNIT_TESTS`, then in
constructor of `ApplicationBT` do the following:

```
ApplicationBT() : mpoStackBT(createStackBT())
```

where `createStackBT` is a function defined as:

```
IStackBT * createStackBT()
{
#ifdef MY_UNIT_TESTS
    return new StackBTMock;
#else
    return new StackBT;
#endif
}
```

This will perform the swapping of implementation during compilation time when you are building your unit test executable. Since you will be performing this swapping on several classes as you write more tests, I suggest that you wrap the factory functions in some class that provides the desired implementations (mock or production) of your classed. For instance, my project has a class named `ImplementationProvider` that performs this task.